# My Call was Blocked on echolink

Tags: echolink

My Call was Blocked on echolink. I have no idea why. I need to reach someone to correct the Problem. My I have my Account since 2002 email changed. It was forwarded to current Email but I discovered It stopped forwarding long ago. Maybe they tried to reach me and because of email problem they could not. If I did something wrong I never knew it. I use it everyday. Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This seems more like an email problem rather than an Echolink problem.

I would check that you can receive emails from other email senders first, to verify that your email account is working.

After you have determined that you can in fact receive emails from other people, then send a support ticket to the Echolink volunteers at this web page and explain your problem.

https://echolink.org/support.htm

I would get them to check first which email address they have for you in their system, then go from there.

Hope that helps !

Comment: I followed your instructions and am waiting for a response from echolink. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if a miscreant connects to your echolink radio station and causes grief to others on the system.  The sysops can block your station to prevent recurrence. The remedy is to establish communications by email to find out what happened.